# Karate : 403 Forbidden error while uploading .xslx file in Karate v0.9.5

Tags: api, file-upload, karate

**We have an API which takes POST request to upload an excel file.**

I am trying to upload a “SampleFile.xlsx” by  using multipart file keyword.

And multipart file filename = {read:'SampleFile.xlsx', contentType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', filename:'SampleFile.xlsx'}

When method post

**And also tried changing contentType to below.**

And multipart file filename = {read:'SampleFile.xlsx', contentType:'application/octet-stream', filename:'SampleFile.xlsx'}

When method post

**Headers information:**

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=“SampleFile.xlsx"[\r][\n]" .
CSRF token, JSESSIONID and application specific authentication parameters are also used during the POST call.

Other APIs of the same application are working fine with same cookies and headers.

**We are getting 403 error as below. We also observed that the file content is converted into binary.**

"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary[\r][\n]”
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-5 >> “/core.xmlPK[0x1][0x2]-[0x0][0x14][0x0][0x6][0x0][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0]![0x0][0xc2]^Y[0x8][0x90][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x1b][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x10][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x10]/[0x0][0x0]docProps/app.xmlPK[0x5][0x6][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][\n]"
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-5 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"

The same request works fine on Postman and Jmeter.

Please help me out !

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: (Adding cURL code and also all possible ways I tried)

```
—cURL from Chrome—
```

curl 'https://samplexlsx.com/rest/upload' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Origin: https://samplexlsx.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Cookie: dslang=GB-EN; acn01-uat=XXXXX==; acack-uat=XXXXXX; JSESSIONID=XXXXX.node0; xlsx_IT_srv_id=xxxxdd' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) WebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryeqxxxxx' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://samplexlsx.com/' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'X-CSRF-Token: xxxxxxx+SjpXDA=' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryeqxxxxx\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=“sample.xlsx"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryeqxxxxx--\r\n' ———compressed

—cURL from Postman--

curl --location --request POST 'https://samplexlsx.com/rest/upload' \
--header 'X-CSRF-Token: xxxxxxx+SjpXDA=' \
--header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
--header 'Referer: https://samplexlsx.com/' \
--header 'Host: samplexlsx.com' \
--header 'Cookie: dslang=US-EN; acn01-uat=xxxxxxx==; acack-uat=xxxxxxxdddd; JSESSIONID=xxxxxddd.node0' \
--form 'file=@/path/to/file’

SOLUTIONS LIST:

```
#1.
Given url 'https://samplexlsx.com/rest/upload'
And def MultipartPayload = {}
And set MultipartPayload
  | path        | value                                                               |
  | read        | "classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx"                                    |
  | contentType | 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' |
  | filename    | 'sample.xlsx'                                                       |
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) WebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
And multipart file file = MultipartPayload
When method post

#2.
And def MultipartPayload = {}
And set MultipartPayload
  | path        | value                            |
  | read        | "classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx" |
  | contentType | 'application/octet-stream'       |
  | filename    | 'sample.xlsx'                    |
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
And multipart file file = MultipartPayload
When method post

#3.
And multipart field file = {read:'classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx', contentType:'application/octet-stream', filename:'sample.xlsx'}
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#4.
And multipart file file = {read:'classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx', contentType:'application/octet-stream', filename:'sample.xlsx'}
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#5.
And form field Content-Disposition = 'form-data'
And form field name = 'file'
And form field filename = 'sample.xlsx'
And form field Content-Type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#6.
* def temp = karate.readAsString('classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx')
And multipart file file =  { value: '#(temp)', filename: 'sample.xlsx', contentType: 'text/xlsx' }
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#7.
And bytes data = read('classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx')
And multipart file file = { value : '#(data)', filename: 'sample.xlsx', contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#8.
And multipart field read = "classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx"
And multipart field filename = 'sample.xlsx'
And multipart field contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post

#9.
And multipart entity read('classpath:testdata/sample.xlsx')
* def headerString1 = {  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'X-CSRF-Token' : 'xxxxddd', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Host': 'samplexlsx.com', 'Origin': 'https://samplexlsx.com', 'Referer': 'https://samplexlsx.com/', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/11.0.1)'}
And configure cookies = cookiesGen
When method post
```

Error-log:
[Error-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWA0x.png)

Comment: go through these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+multipart - if you want any chance of help, paste a cURL command that works

Comment: Hey peter, please check the EDIT on this question.

Comment: that's too much info which I am not going to read. I looked at the postman cURL, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved now.   "CSRF-Token" in header was concatenated with another symbol. Debugged it with the help of developers .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
And multipart file file = { read: 'SampleFile.xlsx', contentType:'application/octet-stream', filename:'SampleFile.xlsx' }
```

Note that the field name here is `file`, also read these updated docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#multipart-file

Comment: Thank you for response. "This" is exactly what I mentioned above in SOLUTION #4 , means, I did try this solution earlier and also tried now after you said. Still getting the same 403 error, I have edited the question again and ATTACHED screenshot of the error-log part.

Comment: @VijayEte this is my last comment on this thread, I am giving up. many others have been able to do this. you can wait for someone else to help you or you can follow this process. all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue